# Is there a comic dealing with Age of Ultron's future?

Tags: marvel, avengers

I've just finished reading the Age of Ultron comic (the paperback collected edition, if that helps), and the story basically goes that:

> Ultron is attacking from the future and some of the remaining Avengers travel forwards through time to defeat him. There's a brief scene of them arriving in Ultron's city, where Stark comments that it's beautiful.

However:

> The story then focuses on Wolverine, who takes it upon himself to travel back into the past to prevent Ultron from being created at all. The events unfolding in the future are never revisited.

I'd definitely be interested in seeing more of the world Ultron crafted for himself.

I appreciate that whatever the Avengers may have done in the future will have eventually been rendered moot by the actions of Wolverine, but I'm also aware that the events of Age of Ultron covered many titles and tie-ins.

Was there ever anything else following the exploits of the Avengers as they moved on Ultron in the future?

Comment: He shows up in a friendly capacity in Old Man Logan, which I think occupies a space on the What If side of the spectrum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment, no. This was one of the common criticisms of that storyline, there's this whole Ultron-controlled future storyline that's completely ignored.

The closest that we see of this is in recent issues of *Avengers* (that's [*Avengers Volume 5*](http://marvel.wikia.com/Avengers_Vol_5)).  In *Avengers* #31, a group of Avengers thrown 500 years into the future, where they end up on an Earth that's ruled by Ultron.  In *Avengers* #32, we learn that Ultron had the capability to send himself (well, he'd send copies of himself) through time from that era.  This matches what we see of the Ultron-controlled future in *Age of Ultron*.

However, there's just one issue spent in that era, and it's part of a storyline (collected in [this collection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785154787)) focused on other subjects.  That storyline doesn't make much sense if you haven't been following the current meta-plot of Marvel.  The incursions in *New Avengers*, the expanded and shifting roster of the current *Avengers*; these are the building blocks of the storyline that touches on the Ultron future.  If you're not familiar with them, it may not be worth it to pick up that collection or the single issues, but I mention it for completeness sake.